# Keep values in a flat array where a desired substring is case-sensitively found

Tags: php, arrays, substring, filtering, case-sensitive

I have this array:

```
array 
  0 => string 'http://example.com/site.xml' 
  1 => string 'http://example.com/my_custom_links_part1.xml' 
  2 => string 'http://example.com/my_custom_links_part2.xml' 
  3 => string 'http://example.com/my_custom_links_part3.xml'
  4 => string 'http://example.com/my_some_other_custom_links_part1.xml'
```

and this code to get the links that contain "my_custom_links" in their name (but not "my_come_other_custom_links")

```
$matches = array_filter($urls, function($var) { return preg_match("/^my_custom_links$/", $var); });
        
echo "<pre>";
print_r($urls); // will output all links
echo "</pre>";

echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches); // will output an empty array
echo "</pre>";
```

I should get an array with 3 items but I am getting an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is wrong.

```
preg_match("/^my_custom_links$/"
```

will match only string which is `my_custom_links`. Change it to

```
preg_match("/my_custom_links/"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$urls = array (
  0 => 'http://example.com/site.xml' ,
  1 =>  'http://example.com/my_custom_links_part1.xml' ,
  2 =>  'http://example.com/my_custom_links_part2.xml' ,
  3 =>  'http://example.com/my_custom_links_part3.xml',
  4 =>  'http://example.com/my_some_other_custom_links_part1.xml');

    $matches = array_filter($urls, function($var) { return preg_match("/example.com/", $var); });

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($urls); // will output all links
    echo "</pre>";

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($matches); // will output an empty array
    echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is incorrect as it checks for those strings which `^(starts)` and `$(ends)` with `my_custom_links` only

```
^my_custom_links$
```

it should be simply

```
\bmy_custom_links
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, the only thing is wrong is you regular expression.
The reason why it doesn't work is because you have this `^` at the beginning which means to match the specified value at the beginning of it and then you have `$` which means to match that string at the end of the string value specified.

Use this instead

```
preg_match("/my_custom_links/" .. rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are filtering by a literal / non-dynamic pattern, there's no real reason to use regex.  Use `array_filter()` with `str_contains()` to keep all values which contain the desired substring. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Xf4HJ))

```
$needle = 'my_custom_links';
var_export(
    array_filter(
        $array,
        fn($haystack) => str_contains($haystack, $needle)
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => 'http://example.com/my_custom_links_part1.xml',
  2 => 'http://example.com/my_custom_links_part2.xml',
  3 => 'http://example.com/my_custom_links_part3.xml',
)
```

---

The truth is that using `array_filter()` with `preg_match()` is actually an antipattern -- this should always be replaced by `preg_grep()` which filters values using a regular expression.  If your logic required case-insensitivity, start/end of string anchors, word boundaries, multibyte support or otherwise had dynamic requirements, a regex would be appropriate.